# Why doesn't react update the image after updating it (updated URL equals to the previous URL)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-select

imagine I have a form that displays a user's information and I also have a user icon that shows the user's image. when a user updates his profile including his avatar I update user Information everywhere that I used it with react-redux and all information will change well. except the user's photo. it doesn't change I think it's for the URL of the photo. The updated photo URL is equal to the previous URL (I change the photo and the URL is made from the user's ID).
I don't know how can I force react to retrieve the new photo

Comment: sound like a form issue, when selecting the image (I presume using a input type="file"), check the values for the form before they are submitted